# Why is {a^nb^n | n <= 10} regular?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, finite-automata, fsm, formal-languages

I understand that
{ a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>n</sup> | n>=1 } is not regular using Pumping Lemma.

But then, how is { a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>n</sup> | n<=10 } regular? I thought we couldn't store the number of a and b in an automata. And I couldn't verify it with pumping lemma too.

Comment: Your question title says >= 10 but the question body says <= 10, and the difference is that for <= 10 the language is finite. A DFA can "store" a finite amount of state, that's what the F stands for.

Comment: @kaya3 oh sorry for that, I've fixed the title. And thank you for the answer. But is there a way to formally prove this? How should I approach a proof?

Comment: A pretty straightforward proof would be to just write out a regular expression like `ε | ab | aabb | aaabbb | ... | aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb` which accepts exactly the language described, proving that it is regular. Or you could just state as a theorem that all finite languages are regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every language that has a finite number of strings as members is regular, because you can construct a finite automaton that accepts each of these strings.

You can prove it by just constructing the automaton. It has a finite number of states and by the [Myhill–Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) all of the strings this automaton accepts belong to a regular language.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do I formally prove this? What approach should I take?

Comment: You are welcome. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can design a finite state automata for the given language. Hence it is regular.